# Loops through other loops

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Loops through other loops
I am trying to insert data from `views.py` context. How can I avoid in this case looping through other loops. How can I fix it?

I am fetching data from wiki by using beautifulsoup. Uploading Image.

It returns this:
[image]

template.html

```
{%extends 'profilecontent/base.html' %}
{%block content%}
    <div class="container-home">
        <div class="home-wrapper home-wrapper-first">
            <p class='home-matches'>Przyszłe mecze <span class='home-week'>W3 D2</span></p>
                <div class="match-wrapper">
                    <table>
                        {%for second_team in second_team_names%}    
                        {%for first_team in first_team_names %}
                        {%for hour_game in hours_games%}
                            <tr><td>{{first_team}}</td><td>{{hour_game}}</td><td>{{second_team}}</td></tr>    
                        {%endfor%}
                        {%endfor%}
                        {%endfor%}
                    </table>             
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-wrapper home-wrapper-second">

        </div>
    </div>
{%endblock%}
```

views.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



def home(request):

    source = requests.get('https://lol.gamepedia.com/Ultraliga/Season_3').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    first_team_names = []
    second_team_names = []
    td1s = None
    td2s = None
    hours_games = ['17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30']


    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable matchlist')

    for table in tables:
        td1s = table.find_all('td', class_='matchlist-team1')
        td2s = table.find_all('td', class_='matchlist-team2')

    for td in td1s:
        span = td.find('span')
        first_team_names.append(span.text)

    for td in td2s:
        span = td.find('span')
        second_team_names.append(span.text)

    context = {
        'first_team_names':first_team_names,
        'second_team_names':second_team_names,
        'hours_games':hours_games,
        }

    return render(request, 'profilecontent/home.html', context)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't try to do stuff like this in a template. Use the greater power of Python over the template engine, to generate a list of elements in the right order for a simple single template loop to format. Pass it in your context.

Comment: Please include the output you're getting in the question, as well as your expected output and any errors.

Comment: The output should be posted as text, rather than as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `zip` your three list in view and send it to your template. Then iterate it over there simultaneously as below...

```
def home(request):

    ...Your Logic...

    context = { "all_teams": zip(first_team_names, second_team_names, hours_games)}

    return render(request, 'profilecontent/home.html', context)
```

Now, unzip in your template and iterate it simultaneously...

```
{%extends 'profilecontent/base.html' %}
{%block content%}
    <div class="container-home">
        <div class="home-wrapper home-wrapper-first">
            <p class='home-matches'>Przyszłe mecze <span class='home-week'>W3 D2</span></p>
                <div class="match-wrapper">
                    <table>
                        {% for data in all_teams %}

                            <tr><td>{{ data.0.first_team }}</td><td>{{ data.2.hour_game }}</td><td>{{ data.1.second_team }}</td></tr>    

                        {%endfor%}
                    </table>             
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-wrapper home-wrapper-second">

        </div>
    </div>
{%endblock%}
```